# How to fetch swift data objects without causing memory issues?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have been building an audio player application and have a tab in my app that queries the Song model (songs added by the user). The issue is that whenever the UI changes, swiftdata fetches the entire model multiple times; this would be fine if I had less than 50 Song objects but as the database grows, fetches put more strain on the main thread even when users perform simple action. I do not know how to fetch in a more efficient way whenever the UI changes.

this is a snippet from my code, whenever I select the ellipsis on the song from the foreach loop, a sheet comes up.

```
struct FrPlayerApp: App {
    @AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode = false
    @StateObject private var timerManager = SleepTimerManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabControl()
                .preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark: .light)
        }
        .environmentObject(timerManager)
        .modelContainer(
            for: [Song.self, Library.self, Album.self], isAutosaveEnabled: false)
}
```

```
struct LibraryView: View {

    @Environment(.modelContext) private var context

    @Query(sort: \Song.title, order: .forward) var songs: [Song]

    @State private var isPresentingUser: Song? = nil

    var body: some View {

        ForEach(songs, id: .id) { song in

            VStack {

                HStack(spacing: 5) {

                    HStack {

                        Text(song.title)
                            .frame(height: 40)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .font(.subheadline)

                        Spacer()

                    }

                    // ... (other code)

                    HStack {

                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")

                    }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isPresentingUser = song
                    }

                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(height: 60)

            }

            Divider()

        }
        .sheet(item: $isPresentingUser) { song in
            librarySongSheet(song: song)
                .presentationDetents([.height(CGFloat(310))])
        }

    }

}
```

at 23 seconds I clicked on the ellipsis to open up the sheet and all of the objects in the database got fetched multiple times, this happens whenever the UI changes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to perform the fetching in a function and decide yourself when that function should be called to update the UI.

Change the `songs` array first

```
@State private var songs = [Song]()
```

And you need access to a `ModelContext`

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
```

Add a function

```
private func loadSongs() {
    let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Song>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\Song.title)])
    
    do {
         songs = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
    } catch {
         // Error handling here or make the function throw
    }
}
```

And then use some relevant modifier to call the function

```
//... view code
}.onAppear(loadSongs)
```